Too many connections
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: mysqli sql exception.
Message: Too many connections
Filename: /var/www/bitbaroda.com/system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli driver.php.
Line Number: 201
Backtrace:
File: /var/www/bitharoxia.com/application/helpers/common helper.php
Line: 312
Function: database
File: /var/www/bitbaroda.com/application/controllers/Home.php
Line: 11
Function: get_settings:
File: /var/www/bitbaroda.com/index.php
Line: 289
Function: require_once
Iam using Academy LMS - Learning Management System
i have setup 6 local setup my website working fine but today it showing
This site can’t be reached
